# How do I get the size of a Linux or Mac OS X directory from the command-line?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, command-line

What command do I use to find the size of all the files (recursively) in a Linux or Mac OS X directory?

Comment: you can use `-k` option to use block size of 1K-byte

Comment: I just want to recommend this free software called Disk Inventory X. download it here http://www.derlien.com/ it's simple to use for mac osx

Comment: Instead of `du`, I use `ncdu`, you can find the reference here, https://remysharp.com/2018/08/23/cli-improved

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The BSD version of `du` used in OS X reports size with 512-byte blocks -- the sizes are essentially rounded up to the next 512-byte value. This tells you the space on disk, which is larger than the amount of data. If you have a lot of small files, the difference can be large.

Here's an example.

This is the value with regular `du`. It's in 512-byte blocks:

```
$ du -s
248   .
```

The `-h` flag results in a more readable number, in kilobytes. As expected, it's half the number of 512-byte blocks:

```
$ du -hs
124K  .
```

Finally, you can use `find` and `awk` to give you the sum of actual bytes in the files. This is kind of slow, but it works:

```
$ find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}'
60527
```

This value matches exactly the number reported by Finder's Get Info window. (There are no weird forks or xattrs in this set of files.) It's significantly smaller than the value reported by `du`.

Here's how it works: it gets a list of all the files, and passes them to `ls -l`; then `awk` is used to count up the bytes. The `-type f` flag is there so that only files (and not directories) get sent to `ls`. Without that flag, it'll also send directory names to `ls`, and each file will be listed twice : once as an individual file, and once as an item in the directory.

The GNU version of `du` can give values in actual bytes instead of blocks. It's unfortunate that the BSD version of `du` is not as flexible.

Comment: Great explanation. Interestingly when using `du` from GNU coreutils with the `-b` option I get a different result than with your `find` pipe. For a 36 GB directory I get a 82 KB difference.

Comment: is there any way to print this out in a more human readable format?

Answer (score 80):

Show the size of a single file

`du -h path_to_a_file`

Show the size of the contents of a directory, each sub-directory, and each individual file:

`du -h path_to_a_directory`

Show the size of the contents of a directory:

`du -sh path_to_a_directory`

Comment: `du -sch` if you want something more easily readable.

Comment: @Johannes, I guess you should post this comment as an answer, so it can be accepted?

Comment: I find the -c option redundant (at least on Mac OS X) and du -sh supresses the subtotals.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know one could accept one's own answer. Now at least people know the question is solved.

Comment: I'll happily accept a new answer that is an improvement on mine.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `du -ah .` which displays sizes of all files and directories recursively.

This can be combined with `sort`, so you'll see the top-20 biggest directories in the current folder:

```
du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20
```

Note: Option `-h` for `sort` is not available on OSX/BSD, so you've to install `sort` from `coreutils` (e.g. via `brew`) and apply the bin path to `PATH`, e.g.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH" # Add a "gnubin" for coreutils.
```

Otherwise use:

```
du -a . | sort -rn | head -20
```

Comment: First command not work on my macOS 10.12.1
#du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20
sort: invalid option -- h
Try `sort --help' for more information.

Comment: @nucleartux Check the note below the command. This works in GNU sort which you can install on macOS via: `brew install coreutils`, otherwise use the BSD sort command at the end without `-h`.

Answer (score 11):

**du** - tells the *disk use* not the *file size*.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f%z | awk '{b+=$1} END {print b}'
```

above terminal code (im on osx 10.6) offers for me the best result and is waaay faster than "find ... -exec"

a quick benchmark

```
time find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f'%z' | awk '{b+=$1} END {print b}'
4744010970

real    0m0.086s
user    0m0.029s
sys 0m0.073s

time find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}'
4744010970

real    0m18.515s
user    0m2.929s
sys 0m9.339s
```

Comment: If you want to do the same on Ubuntu:
`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c%s | awk '{b+=$1} END {print b}'`

Comment: is there a way to get this result in a human-readable format?

Comment: I use rsync because it reports the same as Finder and is very fast: `rsync -avzh -n --stats "/path/to/directory" | grep 'total size is' | awk '{ print $4 }'`

Answer (score 2):

I combined all your approuches and combined it with a human readable output the result is:

```
#!/bin/sh
find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f'%z' | awk '{b+=$1} END {print b}' | awk '{ sum=$1 ; hum[1024**3]="Gb";hum[1024**2]="Mb";hum[1024]="Kb"; for (x=1024**3; x>=1024; x/=1024){ if (sum>=x) { printf "%.2f %s\n",sum/x,hum[x];break } }}'
```

Link to the gist: https://gist.github.com/mlegenhausen/9365461

Comment: This doesn't work on macOS. The output is `find: illegal option -- t`