# List directories and their sizes in Mac OS X command line

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the size of a Linux or Mac OS X directory from the command-line?](https://superuser.com/questions/22460/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-linux-or-mac-os-x-directory-from-the-command-line)

I am in a folder, and I want a list of all the sub-directories and their total sizes.

I dont' want it to list all the sub-directories and files in a recursive manner, just the top level directories and the total size it uses on my drive.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: @Matteo I'd say that this question does not show research effort. In fact, the *Related* list shows the question which is essentially a duplicate, which means the OP should have seen it when they were searching for an answer to their question before they posted it.

Comment: @slhck I agree but I was more hinting that a down vote should be commented (or the question flagged).

Comment: @slhck And actually the question is not an exact duplicate. In the possible duplicate nobody speaks of excluding files (du -hs * does not differentiate ...)

Comment: @slhck I'm doing "research effort" right now just came across this page as most prominent Google hit. What does that say about your comment?

Comment: @geotheory It's great that you searched first and found a helpful answer, and don't need to ask the same question (yet) again. Not sure what you're getting at? Matteo asked for a possible downvote reason, and I explained the most likely one. One reason we ask for research effort is to prevent duplicate questions from happening, and if this one is ranked highly on Google, even better.

Comment: Hi. I'm not commenting on down-voting.  It's more a generic observation (probably belonging in meta) that I've solved innumerable problems using SO/SE pages that feature comments to the effect of 'should've checked google'..

Comment: for mac users, I just want to recommend this free software called Disk Inventory X. download it here http://www.derlien.com/ it's simple to use for mac osx

Answer (score 96, accepted):

With `du` you can compute the size of a directory:

```
du -hs dir
```

if you have only directories you can just (`-h` will return a human readable units, `-s` will not recurse)

```
du -hs *
```

if in the folder you have contains files and folders:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec du -hs {} \;
```

`find` will list all the directories (`-type d`) in the current folder (`-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`) and execute `du` on them.

Comment: FYI - As is this command generates a warning: _find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments._

Solution: `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec du -hs {} \;`

Comment: @Bisonbleu Thanks, I edited the answer. BTW I don't get any warning on High Sierra.

Comment: For the record, I'm on Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: @Matteo How to sort the result?

Comment: @Dr.jacky Remove the ```-h``` option to ```du``` (size in bytes) and pipe the result to sort. E.g, ```du -s * | sort -n```

Answer (score 1):

Try typing the following from inside the directory you're interested in

> du

Works on unix so should work on mac

Comment: Yes but it lists all the files and folders seperately, I just want the folder sizes (totals).